# How to fix this exception use %tb to see full trackback. SystemExit: 1?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jupyter-notebook

An exception has occurred, use `%tb` to see the full traceback.

> SystemExit: 1

I am not getting the solution

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
        return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

I expect it should not give this exception

Comment: some module called `sys.exit(1)` when they should have raised an explicit & specific exception. Then it was catched somewhere.

Comment: What should I do to solve?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Why not post a proper answer for that?

Comment: I can't really answer / solve OP issue. I was just explaining what probably happens.